# Type mismatch Seq.unfold

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

```
let fibgen (x,y) = if(x < 4000000) then Some(x+y, (y, x+y)) else None

let fibseq = Seq.unfold fibgen (1,1)
```

> **Type Mismatch error on Second line. what am I doing wrong?** I am using F# 2.0

### Answer

> First Done Reset Session on My interactive Window still same error
>   and then Restarted My Project now Working fine.
>
> yes i had below piece of code execued in same session

```
// The option type is a discriminated union.
type Option<'a> =
    | Some of 'a
    | None




Interactive window Output as below

val fibgen : int * int -> Option<int * (int * int)>

> 


Eluer2.fs(27,25): error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
    int * int -> ('a * (int * int)) option    
but given a
    int * int -> Option<int * (int * int)>    
The type '('a * (int * int)) option' does not match the type 'Option<int * (int * int)>'
>
```

Comment: Hi - just copy&pasted your code into my F#-interactive and everything works like a charm ... so maybe there is something wrong with your installation - did you try to restart (VS/Windows)?

Comment: BTW: you are missing the first (two?) values of 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, ...

Comment: What version of F# do you use? I checked it with F#2.0 and it works as expected

Comment: @Carsten König Thanks. i have now restarted project and working fine. while learning f#  - every error has started to look like my stupid mistake :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed by Carsten in a comment, the code works fine if you enter it in clean F# Interactive. Since the compiler complains that `Option<'T>` does not match `'T option`, I would guess that you accidentally wrote some code that re-defined `Some` and `None` before using the `unfold` function. Perhaps you wrote something like this (and evaluated that in F# Interactive):

```
type Option<'T> = 
  | None
  | Some of 'T
```

This hides the standard definitions of `Some` and `None` that are constructors of the `'T option` type defined in the standard F# library (and that are expected by the `unfold` function).

You can reset the F# Interactive session by right-clicking in the window and choosing "Reset Session". This removes previous declarations and the code should work fine.

Comment: Or maybe some version conflict between different FSharp.Core libs? - had some of those when developing in VS11 (.net 4.0) and then use this lib in "old" VS2010

Comment: @CarstenKönig That could also be the case, but I suppose that all F# libraries define the option type as `'T option` and not as `Option<'T>`.

Comment: Genuis! No where on this earth for F# i could have thought of restarting my project. Trust me I have spent few hours trying fix this issue

Comment: @Tomas: was hoping for a moment that Option got included into the framework as Tuples did ;)

Comment: @CarstenKönig That would be nice :-) but I'm afraid it can only happen when C# gets better `switch` statement!

Comment: to be honest: as I do much F# lib in C# UI stuff: it would already help to have a "IsNone"/"IsSome" on the optional<'a>-value instead of having to write Optional<...>.IsSome(value) in C# ... just so annoying if for example the 'a is generic by itself :(

Comment: @CarstenKönig The problem is, `None` is (used to be?) represented as `null` value in the compiled code, so writing `opt.IsSome(...)` would only work if `IsSome` was a C#-compatible extension method. I guess these are provided by FSharpX or easy to define if you want to expose `option` to C# code.

Comment: @TomasPetricek - thank you for your input - indeed I use some extension methods to convert them into my own Option-type if needed - just a shame you have to do this ;)